# Moving all triggers from one database to another

Tags: mysql, triggers, data-migration

I have 2 databases, both of which are exactly same but one have triggers and now, I want to move all my triggers to other database too. Is there any command to migrate all my triggers to other database?

Comment: Backup triggers (usnig MySQLdump) then restore them into second database.

Comment: @Akina How do you "backup triggers"? Mysqldump says "Dumping 'information_schema' DB content is not supported"

Comment: Trigger is not a part of INFORMATION_SCHEMA. This can be backed up with mysqldump or another dumping tool within the database backup while using according command-line option.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Data Export and Data import options

In Data Export choose the tables having triggers and choose the option Dump Triggers and unselect others